# Do download URLs of Firebase Storage objects live forever?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When you upload files to Firebase's Storage then ask for the object URL, you get a publicly accessible URL like `http://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/appname/o/filename?alt=media&token=somelongtoken` no matter what permissions you've set on the object, but the token makes it unguessable. The word "token" suggests that this URL won't live forever. Does it?

The [Javascript reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) for `Reference.getDownloadURL` says: "Fetches a long lived download URL for this object." I'm not sure what they mean by "long-lived," and I haven't seen any elaboration on that elsewhere in the docs. Their examples all have the client request the download URL then use it for a temporary purpose, and they don't say whether it's ok to store it for later.

I also see an article [here](https://medium.com/olricdigital/shorten-firebase-storage-url-via-cloud-functions-663b463312da) where someone wrote a link shortener, suggesting you can keep the URL forever since you wouldn't pass around a shortened link that's temporary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will guaranteed live longer than your app will live.  Practically speaking, it won't live "forever", but you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a source in the docs or something for this, or is it something you've seen through experience?

Comment: You quoted the docs - "long lived" refers to this fact that the lifetime of the URL is longer than you'll ever need.  (Otherwise, wouldn't it just say the exact number?)

Comment: Ah, ok. I was thinking maybe "long-lived" meant long enough to cache but not to rely upon. Facebook's "long-lived" tokens still expire if someone doesn't log in for 90 days, for example. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/)

Comment: I see.  Auth tokens have an implied duration that prevent holders of the token from accessing the account after a reasonable amount of time (else hackers could have persistent access to sensitive material).  URLs are generally implied to be durable over time, unless the content is removed.

Comment: @DougSteveonson That's true. They do say "token" in the URL, which is what scared me. I've seen sites give download URLs that stop working after some time, e.g. Apple's developer downloads page, but it is rare.

Comment: That's not an authentication token, though.  These URLs are accessible to anyone who has it.

Answer (score -1):

Checking back on this, turns out those URLs still work even if you chop off the `token` parameter, provided the file is publicly accessible according to your security rules. So I remove the token because, well, it's weird to have in a static URL.

So just `http://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/appname/o/filename?alt=media`