# What Firebase Storage reference should be saved to RTDB/Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to determine the best way to reference a Firebase Storage (Google Cloud Storage) file in a direct-read database like Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore. Since a read operation to this database does not benefit from a backend that can issue tokens and cache image URLs, it is not clear to me what the most performant way is to store these references.

I have come up with a few options and none of them are a clear winner.

1. Store a path like `/images/foo.jpg` to the database, and use Storage Client SDK to generate a tokenized path with `storage.bucket().getDownloadURL("/images/foo.jpg")`.

   **Pros**: Secure & simple.

   **Cons**: Network call for every single image you want to display hurts performance considerably.
2. Store a tokenized path like `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/storage-bucket-823743.appspot.com/o/images%2Ffoo.jpg?alt=media&token=c6da1e33-f3ff-41e2-a6f0-bdb475a2f6d9` with a super long TTL.

   **Pros**: No extra fetch on the client.

   **Cons**: long string stored in expensive RTDB. What if that token is revoked by mistake? The database is now broken.
3. Store a path like `/images/foo.jpg` to the Database and use public storage rules. Reconstruct into a custom static URL like `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/storage-bucket-823743.appspot.com/o/images%2Ffoo.jpg?alt=media`

   **Pros**: Tiny database use, no extra client fetch, explicit public access, no token to lose.

   **Cons**: URL encoding is super flaky, Storage could change their URL format and we'd be out of luck.

So, those are the options I've come up with, and there may be more. Any suggestions for how to solve this issue? The issue is unique because the Firebase databases don't have the benefit of a custom server to handle a token/caching layer to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single "best way" to store these paths. It all depends on your use-case, your preferences, and the context in which you're implementing it.

I typically use :

1. If I need access to the files to be secured, I store the image path (like in your #1), and then use the Firebase SDK to access the file.
2. If I don't need access to the files to be secured, I store the image path **and** the download URL. This way I can find the image easily based on the path, and use the download URL in non-secured clients.

The con's you mention for these are simply not affecting me. I'd recommend you take a similar approach, and report back when the problem actually occurs.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for the clear and concise response. The download URL you're referring to, is that `.getSignedUrl` in the Firebase Admin SDK? And do you set a super long TTL like 100+ years to keep it available? Ie `{
        action: "read",
        expires: "01-01-2119"
      }`

Comment: Whenever I use `getSignedUrl` I get a monster URL like this. Is this the downloadURL you're referring to? `"https://storage.googleapis.com/skatex-8d802.appspot.com/timeline-videos%2Finstagram%3A15239448540%2F8c9f3d8f.mp4?GoogleAccessId=skatex-`...

Comment: ...`8d802%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=4701974400&Signature=TRIK5XPF0%2BD4QSZUgyDz7to8yyPztkStOay%2FI6%2F2lHubcKauvtBvOYDt92bv3fwqYUqseHsEi2A6MArD0DScJXJrfX2x9AWHRvvbgwkGcvicsA4ny0itesBnfkEFFlSfaHT9dCH6dgsuNFzby3Ln9sN3fN52zZJSCKwSafvjCuMx6Cffre0%2B1vsTKwX%2Bfip170zHCSwqr%2BywR7jMuyCamTRlwEBipWcwn%2Byx4piroZrZVTTME7oioL5Iagwy%2BUG%2BhRsD4hTwIxZOK1mLccho9WJBj0Zd2icU%2FCxPpE2hpL1TpC9XwMWfZfXMuzkwd3QsWQW0CatEBnWmmXmljr451g%3D%3D"`

Comment: I use client-side generated download URLs, as in your own #1 option too. You can also use server-side generated signed URLs, but I haven't done that myself.

Comment: It sounds like you're recommending that clients get a downloadURL and then save that to the database, is that safe? How long do those downloadURLs stay valid for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593002/firebase-storage-getdownloadurls-token-validity, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373076/do-download-urls-of-firebase-storage-objects-live-forever

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen would allowing the client to store the downloadURL in the database open the app up to XSS or CSRF attacks? They could store any arbitrary URL in the db